# Calling module inside another module gives the wrong namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple module like this:

```
module Oauth
  class Something
     def self.do_stuff
        Oauth2::Client.new(...)
     end
  end
end
```

But when I call the do_stuff method, I get an error that says:
`"uninitialized constant Oauth::Something::Oauth2"`

Do I need to do any specific stuff to use Oauth2::Client inside the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Oauth2` is on the root namespace, you can force the constant lookup to start at the top by pre-pending it with `::`.

```
module Oauth
  class Something
     def self.do_stuff
        ::Oauth2::Client.new(...)
     end
  end
end
```